# Make xmodmap Changes Permanent

Tags: linux, keyboard, centos, keyboard-layout, keymap

I made some changes to my keymap by writing:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L
```

in `~/.Xmodmap`

The changes work after running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`

But they will not stick after restart.

I tried adding the command in `~/.bash_profile` but no luck.

Also tried adding `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to Startup Applications.

Apparently some have had success adding a sleep before the command but this did not help me.  It looks like a hack so there should be a better way.

Comment: It might work if you put the command in your `~/.xinitrc` so that the command is ran after X starts.

Comment: @DanD. I tried that too.  It's baffling.  Nothing works but running the command manually.  I even tried using a cronjob which completes without error yet this too does not work.

Comment: My xmodmap mappings get dropped when my bluetooth keyboard sleeps. The settings persist through all sorts of system events such as login and restart but not after keyboard reconnect.